# something to help visualize an iOS aplication workflow, algorithms, methods called etc

Tags: objective-c, ios, visualization

hello a noob question here. I am not sure if I will be able to explain my question correctly, so please bear with me.

I'd like to know if there is a (free, or inexpensive) solution to help visualize (or present to someone) what's happening in a iOS application. Things like what happens first (things initialized, defaults loaded, views drawn etc) then what happens when certain things get touched (buttons, sliders) what happens when certain situations occur. These type of things.

Something like a flowchart, but perhaps cooler with the ability to code snippets, notes, pictures or anything that could help with the visualization. Something like CodeDrawer (which  is C/C++ only) but for iOS applications. I'm hoping someone knows what I'm trying to get across here.

cheers
Rad

Comment: Will you be using this professionally? Are you eligible for a student license?

Comment: not a student, aspiring iOS developer. I think I will give yED and Dia a try. both free, work on a Mac and still under development. tack!

Comment: Dia is a no go (X11 app - yuck!). yED looks like a Java app, but kinda looks OK. I will also test drive OmniGraffle (free to try, then $99)

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your original question? Are you looking for a software design tool? I interpreted it as a tool that would generate visualization from existing code. You mention CodeDraw which is a tool to visualize **existing code**, while Dia and OmniGraffle are tools for creating diagrams etc **before** you start coding. Could you clarify this in your question?

Comment: either or. I wouldn't mind a software solution that would generate everything for me and then let me make adjustments, but if it were to be >$20, then I'd rather draw manually. (my apps are not too complicated atm.)

Answer (score 1):

Structure101 has now support for Objective-C. This would maybe worth a try?

http://scitools.com/blog/2012/01/objective-c-support.html

Comment: I am not sure if you count it as inexpensive...

Comment: I see. $995. Probably not for me then. (at the moment anyway)

Comment: Yes, probably a little bit expensive for me as well, but we have it at my work and I did not realize how expensive it was until now.